# Why I cannot access the image in my drawable folder in android studio?

Tags: android

Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hka1x.png) of my code. I want to access the image in my drawable folder and pass it to a class. However, I have put in  an image name as asif.JPG in a drawable folder but I cannot access it using R.drawable.asif.

Comment: try to Clean Project and Rebuild Project.

Comment: Try to clean after rebuild project should work

Comment: re-launching the project solved the problem.thanks

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code, copy-paste it to your question indented with four spaces instead.

Comment: actually in the screenshot i wanted to show that dropdown of the drawable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do clean build and it will regenerate R.java class.